# Proving measure of set is $0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, measure-theory

> Let $\mu$ be measure on $(X,A)$ and $(A_k)$ sequence in $A$ such that $\sum_k\mu(A_k)<\infty$.
>   Show that the set of points that belong to $(A_k)$ for infinitely many values of $k$ has measure zero under $\mu$.

It's problem from Cohn's *Measure Theory*.

My try:

$\sum_k\mu(A_k)<\infty$ implies $\lim_k\mu(A_k)=0$.
And now I'm stuck =D. What can I do next?

Comment: I believe it is sufficient... let some one confirm it...

Comment: How are X and A defined? (I Assume X is a set on which the measure is defined and A a subset?)

Comment: A is sigma algebra on X

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set you are considering is
$$
\limsup_k A_k:=\bigcap_{k=1}^\infty \bigcup_{n=k}^\infty A_n=\{x\in X\mid x\in A_k\text{ for infinitely many }k\}.
$$
Note that $\limsup_k A_k\subseteq \bigcup_{n=k}^\infty A_n$ for all $k$ and hence
$$
\mu\Big(\limsup_k A_k\Big)\leq \sum_{n=k}^\infty \mu(A_k)
$$
for all $k$. Now conclude.

Comment: And now I use definition for convergence of serie =) great, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If $B$ is your set, $B \subseteq \bigcup_{n =N}^\infty A_n$.